# What approach should I take to Bind data to TreeView?

Tags: wpf, controls, bind

I have an architect question:

I want to use Tree View to display some categories and on each categories if user clicks, need to show total product for that category.

What approach do I need to take?

Currently, I am trying to do:
1) Get Data from Database and load it to DataTable and DataTable is accessable from xaml.
2) Calling DataTable from xaml and binding TreeViewItem from dataTable Column...i.e.,

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=SubCategoriesTable}" Name="trSubCategories">
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Home">
            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=sub_category_name}"></TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

I don't know is it a right approach to go? Or Should I add TreeViewItem in my code behind by looping though each datatable row and column?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx) and bind your `TreeView` accordingly. You can use any object type as the backing for the binding; it doesn't *need* to be a `DataTable`.

You should avoid building out `TreeViewItem`'s in your code behind. It is simply not needed and makes down stream management more cumbersome then it needs to be.

As noted by ChristopherS; Josh Smith has an excellent article on a [TreeView with MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx). Bea Stoliz also has a nice post on [displaying grouped data in a TreeView](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=18).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably **by far** the best tutorial you can find about this topic: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx